# XML in XML query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with querying XML data in SQL Server 2012. I have a database that has a table `Parameters_XML` with columns

```
id, application, parameter_nr flag, value
```

The `parameter_nr` is for eg 1 and the value for that parameter is the following:

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <Item id="1344" flags="257">
      <Row>
        <Item id="1179" flags="257">
          <Str>Gall Studio Design SRL</Str>
        </Item>
        <Item id="1421" flags="257">
          <Str>22204869</Str>
        </Item>
        ...........................
```

I need to retrieve the values for all the applications where the item is 1179 and 1421.

Eg: for the application 1 the value for the item 1179 is Gall Studio Design SRL and so on.

So far I have written the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(x.Value AS XML).value('(/Root/Row/Item[@id="1344"/Row/Item[@id="1179"])[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM 
    Parameters_Xml x
WHERE 
    parameter_nr = 1
```

But I get the following error:

> XQuery [value()]: Syntax error near ')', expected ']'.

Please help me with the valid path for the items required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **close** your `[` after `Item[@id="1344"` - and if you want to value of the `Str` subnode, you need to add `Str` to your XPath:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(x.Value AS XML).value('(/Root/Row/Item[@id="1344"]/Row/Item[@id="1179"]/Str)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM 
    Parameters_Xml x
WHERE 
    parameter_nr = 1
```